# Custom editor commands without using a macro?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to make custom commands without using a macro? I would like to do things like:

- jump down 20 lines
- jump up 20 lines
- editor window scrolls when cursor moves within 15 lines of the bottom/top
- jump by paragraph (meaning: jump to next empty line, or method signature start, whichever comes first)

And of course those numbers would be editable.

I've tried macros, but they're too slow. Basically I want IntelliJ to behave just a bit more like emacs. I'm hoping I don't have to make a plugin, but I will if that's the only option. Just hoping there is a way to do it that I missed.

Comment: Plug-in is probably your only option, you can take a look at [IdeaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you are asking. However, there is a IdeaVIM plugin which lets you do some of the stuff you ask for (install via Preferences->Plugins). There is also an emacs plugin which may give you what you want:  http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/441261

The IdeaVIM plugin is maintained by Jetbrains so it may be higher quality.